# D5600 number of focus points does not display

Tags: focus-point-selection

Camera in AF-A and number of focus points set to 9-39. The view finder only shows a single point, centered, which can be moved manually, pressing shutter to focus never shows the 9-39 points available or changes focus point from center of viewfinder.
In INFO screen there's a grid, lower left where it displays active focus point, there are 11 + in grid where manually you can move the focus point to but, again 9-39 never displays or changes, where ever I move the point to it stays there when I press shutter to focus.
Strangely in Auto, pressing shutter to focus will briefly show possible FP then settle on a single point as the focus point.